# Scrolling through two snap points at once in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a website that uses scroll snapping for 3 viewport-sized `<section>` elements implemented like this:

```css
html, body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
</body>
```

It works perfectly in Firefox but whenever I scroll in a Chromium-based browser it scrolls straight from the first section to the third. Any ideas for why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Update: How does this work out for you?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
section {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;        
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried this but I end up with two scrollbars, no snapping, and anything using absolute or relative position wont work. It just completely breaks.